# Execute Aura controller method without waiting for Apex response

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I've been stuck in a problem and need some inputs.

We have a contact form and on submit of it, we are creating a Case record in the backend.

The problem is, the logic is pretty complex and the form submission at times takes more than 10 seconds. We have optimized our code as much as we could, but we have a lot of background processes on Cases such as PB's, WF's, before and after triggers, etc and all of that combined is making the response too slow.

What we have on the aura component

```
submitCase: function(component, fileNames, fileTypes, files, t0){
    let action = component.get('c.submit');
    action.setParams({
       // set some params
    });
    
    action.setCallback(this,function(response){
        let status = response.getState();
     
        if(status === 'SUCCESS'){
            // some console statements
        }
        else if(status === 'ERROR'){
           // some console statements
        }
    }); 
    
    $A.enqueueAction(action); 
    var cmpEvent = component.getEvent("someEventt");
    cmpEvent.fire({
        // show success message as soon as users submit
    });
},
```

And our apex method looks like this

```
@AuraEnabled 
public static String submit(Case caseRecord, List<String> fileNames, List<String> base64Data, List<String> contentType){
            try{ // create case with assignment rule attached as dmlOptions
            // create ContentVersion records
            // create ContentDocumentLink records to attach the files to cases
            return caseRecord.Id;
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            // "Convert" the exception into an AuraHandledException
            throw handleException(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return '';
}
```

This is a web form and the returning Case ID is of no use to our guest users. Also, they see a success message almost immediately when they submit their data, as you can see in the aura component code.

Now, where I need your help is to understand what's the best way for us to handle this situation - we don't need to wait for the response from Apex.

1. Is it okay to remove the "action.setCallback()" since we simply do not need to see what comes back from salesforce?
2. Move everything in the apex to a future method and immediately send back a response to aura component. I personally don't think this makes much sense because I'm sending a dummy response anyway.

Am I overlooking anything if I go with #1 or are there any better ways of handling this that I am missing.

Thanks in advance.

- Vishal

Comment: If the concern is about time and the code cannot be optimized further, Would it be an option for you to take the details and store it in a lightweight object without any triggers, workflows etc. Give users a success message once the record is saved. Then add a scheduler to pick those records and process the actual logic. That way it would be fast and reliable.

Comment: We have already kept that as an option if there's no better solution available

Answer (score 1):

You should wait for the response. In some cases, if the user thinks the process is done and navigates away from the page or closes the browser, the connection will be terminated, and this may result in the underlying server process *also* being terminated. As such, it may get rolled back.

The future/queueable method approach would be the safest here, since you only need to wait a few milliseconds for the main process to complete. Asynchronous code won't be cancelled if the browser is closed or navigation occurs. Alternatively, you may want to wait anyways.

What happens if the case creation fails? They literally won't know anything is wrong, and assume they'll get support they're never going to get. This sounds like a dangerous proposition if you ask me. If you're okay with potential failures, though, go with some asynchronous processing and you'll be fine.

Comment: My initial idea was to wait until the end but there were instances when the process ran for around 20 seconds and even 30 seconds in very few cases, which isn't ideal and I couldn't think of a better way than to make the process asynchronous.